# php strtotime() messes with date of a different year

Tags: php

I am using php to reformat a date and post it to mysql. Everything works great until I pass dates for next year. For example `Mon, 14 Jan, 2013` will be translated into `2012-01-16`. The format is correct just not the date, I have even tried changing the format I pass it, still no change. Here is what it gets `Mon, 14 Jan, 2013` and here is the php that processes it:

```
$startdate = $_REQUEST['one'];
$start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startdate));
```

any clues as to why the hiccup happens only when we enter a new year, even past years?

Comment: Well, _something_ is wrong with adding `Mon, `. [this](http://codepad.org/BXfxxeX5) works fine though. Edit: It doesn't work either!

Comment: Have you tried `Mon, 14 Jan, 2012`? That's in the past, and it will still fail. (gives you `"2012-01-16"`)

Comment: so even january 1 of this year passes just fine.

Comment: The criteria for judging whether something is working is by looking at where it fails, not where it succeeds. The fact that it works for `Etc, January 1, 2012` does not mean it is working for 2012. The fact that it isn't working for `Mon, 14 Jan, 2012` means it isn't working for the current year at all. The format you are using is not supported by `strtotime`. You can use `date_create_from_format` instead.

Comment: Why are you choosing that format in the first place? It looks very unreliable for me. I mean what if I say `Sun, 30 Oct, 2012` deliberately? I mean you can't expect php to do things like this, don't you think?

Comment: It might be a better idea to use a more powerful parser than `strtotime`, e.g. [`date_create_from_format`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or one of the recommendations from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340437/php-better-date-parser-than-strtotime).

Comment: I am looking into `date_create_from_format ` as we speak and the dates are set by me, the user picks them on a calendar so i control the passing format.

Comment: @Asad can you add your comment to your answer

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman it is more of a comment, really. Not a solution. :)

Comment: yes, but it fixed my issue and I feel like it can help others that may see this question that are in the same position that I was. It was helpful and too the point THANKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181123030006/https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for the list of all valid formats for `strtotime()`. The one you're using is not present.

If you want to use `date_create_from_format` instead, here's how:

```
date_create_from_format("D, d M, Y", "Mon, 14 Jan, 2013")
```

Comment: @Mr.SirKingOsman It isn't working for all other dates. I just gave you an example. `Mon, 14 Jan, 2012` is misinterpreted as `2012-01-16`. This kind of string would be hard to parse anyway, because it is possible to enter a weekday that does not match with the date.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but I control the date and format, the user just picks, I have tried this system however and I see its advantages and it works, thanks!

Comment: Your parameters are reversed. Correct it and I will add back the vote - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php